# Does the detail balanced equation of MCMC implies that the arrows between states are bidirectional?

Tags: markov-chains, sampling

By bidirectional, I mean that the probability of transitioning from or to a connected state is the same, so, instead of writing two arrows, we could draw only one per pair of states.

Comment: Not unless the probability of the two states in the target distribution is the same.

Comment: Oh, that's right. The equation says that P({x}) T({x} -> {x'}) = P({x'}) T({x'} -> {x}).
It doesn't imply that T({x} -> {x'}) = T({x'} -> {x})